# Does $\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{(\ln(k!))^2}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

> Here is my solution, but I'm unsure if it is right (the book I'm using has no solutions only "yes/no" answers):

1. Compare with series $$\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{(\ln(k!))}$$ which we know is divergent.
2. Set $$a_k = \frac{1}{(\ln(k!))^2}$$ and $$b_k = \frac{1}{(\ln(k!))}$$ and compare.
3. $$
   \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_k}{b_k} = \frac{\ln(k!)}{(\ln(k!))^2} = \frac{1}{\ln(k!)} = 0
   $$
4. The limit is 0 so the comparison test for positive series lets us conclude that the series does *not* diverge so it converges.

Is the above right? Are there other methods you can use to prove convergence?

**Edit**: As explained in the answers, the above solution is incorrect. The fixed solution is:

$$\frac{1}{(\ln k!)^2} \leq \frac{1}{(\ln 2^{k-1})^2} = \frac{1}{(k-1)^2(\ln 2)^2} = \frac{1}{(\ln 2)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{(k-1)^2}$$

The rightmost expression is of the form $c_1\frac{1}{(k-c_2)^2}$, where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary positive constants. So the dominoes fall:

$\frac{1}{k^2}$ converges $\implies \frac{1}{(k-1)^2}$ converges $\implies \frac{1}{(\ln 2)^2(k-1)^2}$ converges $\implies \frac{1}{(\ln 2^{k-1})^2}$ converges $\implies \frac{1}{(\ln k!)^2}$ converges.

Comment: If something does not diverge, it is not necessarily true that it will convgere. For example, the sequence $\{-1,1,-1,1,\ldots\}$ does not diverge but it also does not converge, either.

Comment: I do not understand your use of the comparison test.  Other methods: $\log(k!) = \Omega(k\log k)$, so...

Comment: @TonyS.F. Oh interesting. I added that the series should  be positive which (I think!) should cover that case.

Comment: By the Stirling approximation of the factorial, the series is bounded by $\sum1/k^2$.

Comment: I derived this from Euler Mascheroni constant . And the series converges as well check below and tell me if you agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compared your series with a divergent series. But the test is inconclusive in this case, since you got the limit $0$. Besides, you haven't said why the series $\sum \frac{1}{\log (n!)}$ is divergent. In fact, 
$$\frac{1}{\log (n!)} \simeq \frac{1}{n \log n}$$ since
$$\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \le n! \le n^n $$ and so 
$$n(\log n -1) \le \log (n!) \le n \log n$$
That comparison is enough to give you convergence, since $\sum \frac{1}{(n \log n)^2}$ is convergent ( in fact already $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent, or even $\frac{1}{n (\log n)^2}$ is also convergent - but not $\frac{1}{n \log n}$).

In general, if you want to prove convergence ( divergence), you may compare with another convergent(divergent) series.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose that means my solution is wrong.

Comment: You are welcome. Your  approach is not correct. Since you want to show convergence, so you should compare with a convergent series. Comparing with a divergent series will always give an inconclusive result. All is correct, except point $4$. But  1,2,3, even if correct, are of no use in proving convergence.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is a brutal shortcut: $\log(k!)$ is a convex function by the [Bohr-Mollerup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem), hence your series is surely convergent by asymptotic comparison with $\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{1}{k^2}$.

Comment: Killing-relatively big-mosquitoes with a cannon! Nice, +1!

Answer (score 1):

Since for $x>0$   $$\frac{x}{x+1}\le \ln(x+1)\le x$$
and Given that [from the Euler Mascheroni's constant,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) we have $$\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1}{j} \sim \gamma+\ln k~~~~as~~~k\to\infty$$ Hence,

$$ \color{red}{ \ln(k!)=\sum_{j=1}^{k}\ln j  \ge \sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{j-1}{j} = k -\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1}{j}  \sim  k-\ln k -\gamma }\sim  k-\ln k     $$

Therefore, 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(\ln(k!))^2} \le C \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(k-\ln k)^2} \le C\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2} $$
This prove the convergence. Indeed, $$\lim_{k\to \infty }\frac{k}{k-\ln k} =\lim_{k\to \infty }\frac{1}{1-\frac{\ln k} k} = 1$$ Then for $k$ large enough we have, $$\frac{1}{(k-\ln k)^2}\le \frac{C}{k^2} $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty u_n$ where $u_n=\frac{1}{(\ln(n!))^2}$.

We have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}= \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\ln(n!))^2}{(\ln((n+1)!))^2}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(\ln(n+1))^2}=0<1$.

Then, using [D'Alembert criterion](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/D%27Alembert_criterion_(convergence_of_series)) , the serie $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(\ln(n!))^2}$ converge.